# how to select element by class name in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to design responsive menu bar that collapses in small screens, however, I am using typescript. is there any clue what equivalent to this code in typescript

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");}
```

I changed to this code in typescript but it never works

```
myFunction(): void {
(<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("topnav"))[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no need to change anything because typescript is a superset of javascript, so even regular javascript can be typescript.

With that being said, you can add some typescript features:

```
function myFunction(): boolean {
    let elements: NodeListOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName("topnav");
    let classes: DOMTokenList = elements[0].classList;
    return classes.toggle("responsive");
}
```

But there's no need to break things apart like that, so you can just have your exact code, but maybe add a return type to the function signature:

```
function myFunction(): void {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

Or

```
function myFunction(): boolean {
    return document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```